# Android/OpenGLES: Pulling x and y coords through my class hierarchy?

Tags: java, android, class, opengl-es

So I'm working on an Android game using OpenGL; it's roughly similar to Breakout. Up until now, I've gotten away with updating the game on every draw frame as the user changes her input. Now, though, I have a ball object whose x and y coordinates I'd like to update regularly. I'm doing this through a game loop, but trying to extract the coordinates is proving more confusing than I expected.

My class hierarchy is like this:
MainActivity has an instance of GameLoop. GameLoop has an instance of Ball. Ball has x and y fields and functions for updating them; the GameLoop calls these functions repeatedly in a new Thread.

MainActivity also has an instance of MyGLSurfaceView, which has an instance of MyRenderer, which draws all of my objects on each draw frame--so this is where I need access to those x and y coordinates.

So what I'm trying to do is pull two variables up through two levels of my hierarchy and down through two different levels. I'm admittedly somewhat new to OOP, and I feel like the whole structure of this program may be misguided, so I'm not sure where to proceed from here. :/

Thank you for your help! I would post code, but I'm not sure which bits would be of any help.

Comment: Breakout for Android, with commentary: https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my opinion what you did is best approach... Your game world is more or less defined in MainActivity, from it it branches to physical part (+user input) in GameLoop and graphic representation in MyGLSurfaceView.

Where you failed is you defined your "ball" in GameLoop instead of MainActivity. I suggest you create all the existing objects in MainActivity and then send them where needed, usually in multiple places. So for your "ball" case you should create an instance of it in MainActivity and set `GameLoop.ball = ball` and `MyGLSurfaceView.MyRenderer.ball = ball`.

In more general case you would create a base class for or your game objects GameObject and then subclass them, base class would probably have methods as `move(double timeInterval)` and `draw()` depending on the game. Now your MainActivity will hold some type of array to hold all GameObject objects and be responsible for creating those objects and sending them to other classes such as drawing engine or physics engine which should also have an array where those objects can be stored for usage.

Now if you managed such hierarchy your drawing engine will only loop through its internal array and draw all the objects (beside setting up matrices and parameters) which is just what it should do. Note it will not even have to know those X,Y positions since those are only used in draw() method which is part of the GameObject itself. The same goes for physics part of your game.

There are a few things you should note here about multithreading though.. In your case you seem to have at least 3 threads: MainActivity, GameLoop, MyRenderer. You can not just add an object from MainActivity array to MyRenderer array at any time, you should queue messages to GameLoop to collect the objects and add them to its array when the rendering cycle completes, same goes for removing and also GameLoop thread. Another thing is loading the GL content: All the loading should be on a single thread (MyRenderer) so although MainActivity thread created the item it should not initialize any GL loading, MyRenderer thread should ask the object if GL part has been loaded and call the loading if needed, same goes for deleting. And another thing is GameLoop thread is in many cases the one that will get commands to create/remove object (user double taps -> create new ball), never create the object directly on that thread, make a system to send a message to MainActivity to do that.

Although this question does not have anything to do with openGL, the architecture of a game engine is very important and should be planned ahead. I hope you will get some use of this answer in both, using OOP and designing an engine. Also note there are many great ways to create an engine such as this and others might disagree or have better solutions.